# Cloud Build with Github trigger not working: testIamPermissions not found on server

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to implement an automation using Python and Google Cloud Run, and the automation is running well. But to avoid having to manually deploy it everytime, I am tryin to implement Github trigger in Cloud Build.

I created a dockerfile, the yaml file, requirements, etc., just as recommended [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run).

It all starts fine, the dockerfile, yaml and requirements are used properly, but in step 3 I get an error:
[image]

Details of the error follows:

```
Step #2: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest
Step #2: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest
Step #2: ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) HTTPError 404: <!DOCTYPE html>
Step #2: <html lang=en>
Step #2:   <meta charset=utf-8>
Step #2:   <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
Step #2:   <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
Step #2:   <style>
Step #2:     *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
Step #2:   </style>
Step #2:   <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
Step #2:   <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
Step #2:   <p>The requested URL <code>/v1/projects/[prject-id]/locations/REGION/services/[application]:testIamPermissions</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
Step #2: 
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

I believe I granted all required permissions, but I can't seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue: the region was incorrect in the yaml file.

Comment: would you mind to provide a bit how did you fixed this issue? how was the yam before and what did you changed?

Answer (score 0):

I am not the original poster, but I came across the same problem. The command that I was using was:

```
  - id: 'deploy-cloud-run'
    name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args: [
      'run', 'deploy', '*** NAME ***',
      '--port', '8000',
      '--image', '*** IMAGE ***',
      '--region', 'europe-west3-a',
      '--min-instances=0',
      '--max-instances=1',
    ]
```

However `europe-west3-a` is not a valid zone. It should be `europe-west3`. Check [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/locations) page for the correct zone id